# Battery power supply and safe shutdown on power outage

Tags: power-supply, battery, ups

I'm completely new with Raspberry Pi. In fact I'm just planning to buy a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, but I don't have anyone yet. I want it to be running 24/7 so I'm worried about power outages. I've been googling around and the cheapest solution I've found is [this one](http://raspi-ups.appspot.com/en/index.jsp).

**From the link (just in case it goes down):**
The idea is to connect the Pi this way:
[image: Raspberry Pi connection to detect power outage]

And then use upsd to detect power outage (based on ethernet disconnection)

But I haven't found any reviews about it. I wanted to make sure it would work and if there is any pros/cons compared to other solutions (that are more expensive) like GertDuino, mini UPS, UPiS, etc

Also, what specifications should I look for in the battery bank? (beside being able to charge and supply power at the same time)

Thanks

Comment: I think I will delete the post Diego. I don't have a math of the usage. May be I can check once and then get back to you

Comment: @VaradAG, it wasn't exactly what I was asking but it was useful anyway. If you, by any chance, can test the upsd software to detect ethernet connection/disconnection I'd really appreciate it. Thanks again for sharing your info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to setup what I posted and the good news is that the idea works. I tried unplugging the ethernet wire and the raspberry powered off. However the battery I bought which had pass-through (required to do what I wanted) when the input is unplugged it stops giving energy to the raspberry for less than a second and then it starts again. I'm not sure if this happens with all pass-through batteries or just some models. For further reference my battery is this one: [RAVPower Deluxe Series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017VBBVE4).

Answer (score 0):

the german magazin "CT" made an Article about the [Drawdown](https://www.heise.de/select/ct/2017/20/1506369689396119). Their solution is a Big Capacitor 10000µF with 6,3V between the 5V and the GND Pins. Probably you need an Indutivity (Fastron 07HCP for example) in a series Connection between the 5V Pin and the Capacitor.
Best regards,
Bastian

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to determine how much power the Pi consumes; in my case (a Pi 4 and a 7" HDMI screen) it is 8W.
Then you would try and find a power bank/UPS that fits your needs for how much time the Pi needs to stay on after an outage; again in my case a 5V/1,6A (8W) power bank would be all I need for an hour.

For the safe shutdownd part, things get more complicated because you would have to know (have a cue) as to when do it, and the only way I see you doing it is knowing the battery voltage (as it discharges).